# Inquietud sobre permutacion de numeros

Tags: php

Buen dia amigos. Veran, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
function permutate($elements, $perm = array(), &$permArray = array()){
    if(empty($elements)){
       array_push($permArray,$perm); return;
    }

    for($i=0;$i<=count($elements)-1;$i++){
       array_push($perm,$elements[$i]);
       $tmp = $elements; array_splice($tmp,$i,1);
       permutate($tmp,$perm,$permArray);
       array_pop($perm);
    }

    return $permArray;
}

$p = permutate(str_split($_POST[numero]));
$result = array();
$result = array_unique($result);
```

Ese codigo lo que hace es que me muestra todas las permutaciones posibles de un numero sin repeticiones. Por ejemplo, si deseo permutar el numero: 1234 me muestra las siguientes permutas.

```
1234
1243
1324
1342
1423
1432
2134
2143
2314
2341
2413
2431
3124
3142
3214
3241
3412
3421
4123
4132
4213
4231
4312
4321
```

Lo que yo estoy buscando es que el codigo me muestre un resultado como el siguiente

```
1234 - 1243 - 2143 -2134
```

Es decir, que haga la permutacion de numeros en grupos de 2, los dos primeros y los dos ultimos (12 y 34) y me arroje las 4 permutaciones posibles.

Agradezco mucho su ayuda de antemano

Comment: Porque no simplemente generas 4 variables, y las concatenas? las  primeras 2 variables tendrian, los primeros dos caracteres y los ultimos dos, la tercera variable tendria los primeros dos caracteres invertidos, y en la ultima solo tendrias los ultimos dos invertidos, luego ya solo concatena las variables en el orden que necesites.

Comment: Las variables de entrada (ej 1234 ) vienen como string? o son arrays?

Comment: ¿Qué regla se aplicaría si permutas 3 o 5 cifras? ¿O siempre son 4?

Comment: Siempre son 4, logre hacerlo concatenando las variables. Pero no creo que sea la forma mas optima.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías poner esta condición al principio de la función:

```
    if(count($perm) == 2)
        if(($perm[0] != str_split($_POST[numero])[0] || $perm[1] != str_split($_POST[numero])[1]) 
          &&
          ($perm[0] != str_split($_POST[numero])[1] || $perm[1] != str_split($_POST[numero])[0]))
            return;
```

Pero creo que sólo sirve cuando son cuatro números y todos distintos.